# Warning for Dynamically Allocating 2D-arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a c++ code for image detection for which I have two matrices input[60001][785] and
weight[785][60001]. I need to multiply them (done inside mat_mult()) and compute the sigmoid of that result(done inside sigmoid()). The size of the result would be too big which is why I used dynamic allocation for these arrays. However, I'm still getting an overflow warning. When I run the code, I also get the: std::bad_array_new_length error and the code exits. How can I fix this? Is there a better way to declare and use these arrays?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
//#include <gsl/gsl>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int col = 785;   // amount of columns
int lines = 60001; // amount of lines
int x = 0;     // a variable that will contain a value from the file
vector <float> myValues;
float weight[785][60001];
float input[60001][785];


std::vector<float> sigmoid(std::vector<float> matrix)
{
    int i,j;
    matrix.reserve(60001ull * 60001ull); 
     for(i=0;i<60001;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<60001;j++)
         {
             matrix[(static_cast<unsigned long long>(i) * 60001ull) + static_cast<unsigned long long>(j)] = 1/(1+exp(-matrix[(static_cast<unsigned long long>(i) * 60001ull) + static_cast<unsigned long long>(j)]));     //matrix[(i*60001)+j] = 1/(1+exp(-matrix[]));
         }
     }
     

     return matrix;
}

std::vector<float> mat_mult(float a[60001][785],float b[785][60001])
{
    int i,j,k;
    std::vector<float> mult;
    mult.reserve(60001ull * 60001ull);
    //float(*mult) = new float[60001*60001];

    for(i = 0; i < 60001; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 60001; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < 60001; k++)
            {
                mult[(static_cast<unsigned long long>(i) * 60001ull) + static_cast<unsigned long long>(j)] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return mult;
}

int main() {

    int i,j,k,row,column,row_count=0;
    std::vector<float> mult;
    mult.reserve(60001ull * 60001ull);
    std::vector<float> sigmoid_matrix;
    sigmoid_matrix.reserve(60001ull * 60001ull);
    //Read the csv File:
    ifstream ifs ("fashion-mnist_train.csv");
    
    char dummy;
    for ( i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
        for ( i = 0; i < col; ++i){
            ifs >> x;
            //cout<<"value being stored: "<<x<<endl;
            myValues.push_back(x);
            // So the dummy won't eat digits
            if (i < (col - 1))
                ifs >> dummy;
        }
    }
    //Reading csv File completed.



    // Store input in 2-D format for better understanding.
    for(i=0;i<60001;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<785;j++)
        {
            input[i][j] = myValues[(i*785)+j];
        }
    }

    //Multiply input and weight matrix:
    mult=mat_mult(input,weight);
    sigmoid_matrix=sigmoid(mult);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            cout<< sigmoid_matrix[(i*60001)+j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


cout<<"finished execution\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float* sigmoid(float(*matrix) = new float[60001*60001])` means that, by default, calling this function allocates about 14GB of memory (assuming a 4-byte float).  Very few systems will tolerate having to incidentally allocate multiple chunks of such a size - let alone, in your code, where that memory will be leaked on each call.   As a rule of thumb, code which calls for matrices of that sort of size need to be redesigned to use less memory.

Comment: I just realized that I need all arrays to be float so I have changed my code accordingly. But I'm getting the same warnings and error.  And I don't think there is unsigned float in c++. Is there any fix for that?

Comment: No unsigned float built in to C++ and I don't know of any third party libraries that supply them either. Shaving odd a bit isn't going to help much either way.

Answer (score 0):

The variable mult is 3,660,121,001 long. The int type only support from -2147483648 to 2147483647. You will need to use unsigned int which support from 0 to 4294967295 or long long int which is from -(2^63) to (2^63)-1 if you need negative numbers. So it doesn't matter if it's dynamic or not.

For reference in this page you will find all the sizes info, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm

Also, this is the official page of C++ with in-depth details, credits to the comment below.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties

Comment: The C++ Standard guarantees only that `int` will be at least 16 bytes and no larger than `long`. 32 bits is common these days, but 16 and 64 bit aren't unheard of.

Comment: The chart linked is bogus. Here's a better one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, you can use an `std::vector` (a array you are trying to create cannot be larger than `7FFFFFFF = 2 147 483 647` and you are trying to create `60001 * 60001 = 3 600 120 001` items, as mentioned in other answers.

Whereever you define a new array,

```
int(*mult) = new int[60001 * 60001];
```

you can use

```
std::vector<int> mult;
mult.reserve(60001ull * 60001ull);
```

and access your vector similar to an array

```
mult[(static_cast<unsigned long long>(i) * 60001ull) + static_cast<unsigned long long>(j)] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

When you are specifying a large number for the dimensions, you can use the ULL suffix to denote that should use 8 bytes of `unsigned long long` integer value, thus `60001ull`.

I've not tested the full code, but this allows your code to compile, you might have other issues you need to figure out.

Comment: The problem isn't a maximum size of an a array, usually. If `vector` can do it  a `new`ed  array should be able to do it. The integer math was probably overflowing and doing a 2s compliment flip to -5000 or so. Your solution works (and is probably better) but not for the reason you describe in the opening paragraph.

Comment: I tried your fix but I still get an error when I run my code. The error I get is:
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::reserve"  which I think has to do we size. Can you please take a look at the code above? I've added my modified code. Thanks!

Comment: The code you updated above seems to compile in my case. As I've mentioned, I was trying to fix the overflow compiler issue you were seeing. The error you are receiving is probably an exception is thrown, and app just crashes because it is not handled. You can debug line by line to see what is going wrong in my opinion.

Comment: When I use the code `int(*mult) = new int[60001ull * 60001ull];` the compiler gives `error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes` , thus I've recommended to use vector.